# Insert HTML element or replace its contents if it exists

Tags: jquery

I have a following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <!-- here may or may not be: <li></li> -->
</ul>
```

What is the most concise/snippy way to write the following using jQuery:

```
var $firstLi = $('li:first-child');
if (!$firstLi.next().length) {
    $firstLi.after('<li>Two</li>');
} else {
    $firstLi.next().html('Two');
}
```

?

```js
var $firstLi = $('li:first-child');
if (!$firstLi.next().length) {
 $firstLi.after('<li>Two</li>');
} else {
 $firstLi.next().html('Two');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the way you're doing it now? You *could* cache `$firstLi.next()`, but apart from that it is pretty much spot-on.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's too long. There should be a method like `$.insertOrHtml(selector, content);`

Comment: So the code you wrote says if there's more than one list item create a new one, make its content 'Two', and insert it after the first list item, otherwise (there's only one list item) create a new one, make its content 'Two', and insert it after the first list item. What's the goal? Seems like there's no need to check for anything and just insert the list item in the second position regardless.

Comment: @niutech, *there should be a method...* Excellent idea, and you can write that method from the code you already have :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple one-liner:

```
$('li:first-child').next().remove().end().after('<li>Two</li>');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want *concise* way

```
var $firstLi = $('ul li:eq(1)'); // Index is zero based
$firstLi.length ? $firstLi.text('Two') : $('ul').append('<li>Two</li>');
```

If you want *readable* code, then you already have the code.